# EaselJs with SpriteSheet Opacity and Background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs

I have a simple Problem - I currently make sprites and animations using Sprite sheets and easelJS , but I want the white pixels (around the character ) to be clear so the background can be viewed. I think it can be done pixel by pixel but it would be too cost extensive . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like an issue of the image and/image format, not easeljs/SpriteSheet.
Are u using a jpg as your SpriteSheetImage? To have transparency you need to use .png, and to remove the white background you best use Photoshop.